# How to detect model parameter change event in mithril.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mithril.js

I recently started learning mithril.js and I'm wondering how can I make very basic Model -> View one way data binding app.

```
TestModel = function(data){
  this.name = m.prop(data.name)
}
testModel = new TestModel({name: "John"})
```

code above declare a model and it works perfectly as getter/setter.
but how can I set an event listener for the model event like Backbone's `listenTo('model',"change",callbackFunc)`?

all sample codes I saw are setting events for actual user actions like `click`,`keyup` or `onchange`.but never listen to actual model value's state directly.

am I missing something or am I understanding how to use mithril.js wrongly?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the key ideas with Mithril is that changes usually happens after an event:

- A user action like `onclick` or `keyup` defined in a `m()` view template
- An ajax request made with `m.request`

Mithril automatically redraws after those, alleviating the need for most listeners.

If you are updating your models through some other method and you need to redraw manually, use `m.redraw` or `m.startComputation / m.endComputation`. Thanks to Mithril's DOM diff algorithm, redraws are very cheap so don't be afraid to use them (with some common sense, of course!) Check out the [m.redraw](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.redraw.html) documentation for more info.