# Mithril.js m.withAttr: Passing event to another function

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I am going through the [Mithril tutorial](http://mithril.js.org/getting-started.html) and am having trouble understanding `m.withAttr`. The guide has the following line in the view layer:

`m("input[type=checkbox]", {onclick: m.withAttr("checked", task.done), checked: task.done()})`

I have two questions.

1) I understand that the first half, `onclick: m.withAttr("checked", task.done)` means, essentially: 
'set task.done, using m.prop, to the value of the "checked" attribute'. But what is the purpose of the second half, `checked: task.done()`? It seems like it is simply repeating the first half.

2) As I went through the tutorial, I wanted to add the functionality of persisting my Todos to a persistence layer. I created a save function, so that I could refactor the line that I referenced above into something like:

`m("input[type=checkbox]", { onclick: todo.vm.markAsDone.bind(todo.vm, task)})`

And in my view-model, I had the function:

```
vm.markAsDone = function(todo) {
      m.withAttr("checked", todo.done), checked: todo.done();
      todo.save();
    };
```

But this did not work; I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error. I think the problem is that the event is not being properly bound to the `markAsDone` function, so it doesn't understand the `"checked"` attribute; but I'm not sure how to fix this problem (if that even is the problem).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

The second parameter of the `m()` function defines attributes on the HTML element, in this case an `<input type=checkbox>` will be decorated. (The exception is the special *[config](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.html#accessing-the-real-dom-element)* field)

- `checked` determines if the input checkbox is checked, so it is required to *display* the state of the task.
- `onclick` is the event handler that will *modify* the state.

So the attributes do different things, therefore both of them are needed.

**Question 2**

Since `markAsDone` is passed a `todo` model, you don't have to do any `m.withAttr` call there. Simply modify the model, and let Mithril redraw the view. The redraw happens automatically if you call `markAsDone` through an event like `onclick`.

If you want more information about the redraw procedure, I summarized it in a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728976/70894).

Edit: `markAsDone` will probably look like this:

```
vm.markAsDone = function(todo) {
    todo.done(true);
    todo.save();
};
```