# Mithriljs does not update DOM on change in data

Tags: mithril.js

I read somewhere, the DOM is updated every time an event occurs and there is changes in data which are bound to DOM. So I wished to learn more about it. I tried the code below but the DOM is not updated when data in textarea changes but its updated whenever I click or press tab key.

```
var app = {
    controller: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.model = {};
        this.model.errors = [];
        this.break_data = function (value) {
            self.model.errors = value.split(' ');
            m.redraw();
        }
    },
    view: function (ctrl) {
        return m('.content', [
            m('textarea', {onchange: m.withAttr('value', ctrl.break_data)}),
            ctrl.model.errors.map(function (error) {
                return m('.error', error);
            })
        ]);
    }
}

m.mount(document.getElementById('app'), app);
```

I even tried `m.startComputaion()`, `m.stopComputation()` and `m.redraw()` non of them works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redrawing timing is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728976/70894

As for your example, the problem is not Mithril but the event. You need to use `oninput` instead of `onchange` to look for immediate changes. As the [Mozilla docs for the "change" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) states:

> The change event is fired for input, select, and textarea
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value.

Here's a fiddle with your code that uses `oninput`: http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/LuLcra77/

Note that you don't need `m.redraw` in the event handler anymore now when the correct event is used, since Mithril redraws automatically after every event defined in a call to `m()`.